# FOS User Bundle installation error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have followed the [installation guide](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) for FOSUserBundle and got the following error on the step 8:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.fos_userbundle".

This is my security.yml:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:        sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
            form_login:
                check_path: /demo/secured/login_check
                login_path: /demo/secured/login
            logout:
                path:   /demo/secured/logout
                target: /demo/

        main:
            pattern:           ^/
            form_login:
                provider:      fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:            true
            anonymous:         true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Should I register service manually? How to proceed?

Comment: Please provide your security.yml

Comment: @jstephenson I have added it to the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Try* removing the second `providers:` block (so just the `fos_userbundle` one remains) ...

Comment: error occured: InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "fos_userbundle" under "security"

Comment: I mean remove the 'providers: in_memory' block, not the 'providers:' from above fos_userbundle, sorry.

Comment: I had the same issue, but after removing the duplicate provider from security.yml i ran easy extend and auto loaded via https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/7#issuecomment-36505015 and it works perfectly. From there you can enable the `ApplicationSonataUserBundle` bundle and persist via `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.